# Как перевести дату в нужный формат?

Tags: python, json

получаю из json дату в каком то странном формате 2020-02-10T08:50:00Z кто нибудь знает как это привести к формату ДДMM (год не нужен)

Answer (score 7):

Формат у даты никакой не странный, а самый обычный. Для работы с датой используют модуль `datetime`, который позволяет гибко форматировать входные и выходные данные:

```
from datetime import datetime

str = "2020-02-10T08:50:00Z" # строка с вашей датой

PATTERN_IN = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" # формат вашей даты
PATTERN_OUT = "%m%d" # формат даты, который вам нужен на выходе

# переводим строку шаблона PATTERN_IN в объект даты
date = datetime.strptime(str, PATTERN_IN) 
# выводим дату в нужном формате
print(datetime.strftime(date, PATTERN_OUT))
```

Расшифровка форматов [приведена в справке](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

- %Y - год как четырехзначное число
- %m - месяц как двухзначное число (с 0)
- %d - день как двухзначное число (с 0)

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В таком случае можно использовать срезы

```
str = "2020-02-10T08:50:00Z"[5:10].replace('-', '')
print(str)#0210
```

Comment: вообще не разбираюсь в регулярках, буду учить ну подскажи как удалить дефис в результате

Comment: Никакие регулярные выражения здесь не нужны, достаточно использовать срезы списка.

Comment: @Эникейщик, ну, да, можно и так

Comment: Только это все равно неудобно, что срезы, что регулярные выражения (и неизвестно еще, что более неудобно) - если захочется поменять формат вывода или изменится входной формат, то придется перелопачивать весь код. А с модулем datetime нужно будет подправить всего лишь одну строчку.

Comment: @Эникейщик, понял, спасибо, буду знать